# %in% function in R, two arguments

Tags: r, merge, conditional-statements, match

I have been trying to create a dataframe (df3) based on two other dataframes of different sizes(df1, df2) and the following conditions:

Include in df3 all the rows where: df1$id = df2$id and df1$cond=df2$cond

I tried:

```
df3<-df1[(df1$id %in% df2$id &
            df1$fcond %in% df2$cond),]
```

But it selects the rows where at least one of the arguments is true, instead of both.

Dummy data:

```
t<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
id<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
cond <- c(1,5,1,1,1,5,1,1)

df1<-data.frame(cbind(t,id,cond))

id <-c(1,4)
cond <-c(1,1)

df2<- data.frame(cbind(id, cond))
```

Expected output:

```
t<- c(1,7)
id<-c(1,4)
cond<- c(1,1)
df3< c(t, id, cond)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Warning message: In cbind(t, id, cond) :  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be we need

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df1, df2, by = c('id', 'cond'))
```